# How to show data from alfresco database?

Tags: database, api, alfresco

If I want to know a number of all files in alfresco to show on alfresco page how to do that first?

Now I am not find api access to database and if I find api, what should I do next?

Comment: You don't want to talk directly to the database, that's for sure! You probably want to use something like SearchService, NodeService or FileFolderService, depending on exactly what you want to do. When you say "number of all files", do you mean number of cm:content nodes? Number of nodes total? Number of cm:content nodes in a site? etc

Comment: thanks a lot @Gagravarr,now i know i must use FileFolderService, in FileFolderService have many method, [link](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/model/FileFolderService.html),i must use listFiles method?i'm not sure .how to i try a method to view all file in repository alfresco?

Comment: What do you mean by "all file in repository" though? As I've previously said, do you mean number of cm:content nodes? Number of nodes total? Number of cm:content nodes in a site? etc

Comment: i mean number of cm:content nodes. sorry in my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy way, you can query all type in database by api : `localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/query?q={q}` 
q is **CMIS Query Language** for alfresco. example `SELECT * FROM cmis:document` it selects all properties for all documents 
see more [CMIS Query Language](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Query_Language)

Answer (score 3):

You can make a query to SearchService, like this:

```
SearchParameters params = new SearchParameters();
params.getStores().add(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE);
params.setLanguage(SearchService.LANGUAGE_FTS_ALFRESCO);
params.setQuery("TYPE:cm\\:content AND PATH:\"/app\\:company_home/st\\:sites/cm\\:test/cm\\:documentLibrary//*\"");
ResultSet result = searchService.query(params);
System.out.println(result.length());
```

But I'm not sure how optimised it is for performance.

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience sometimes it is better to get such information from database.

Just for info: in my current project we have more than 50000 documents in repo and I need to get exact number for monitoring.

Here is few points to use DB queries in **some cases**:

1. CMIS is (much) slower (in my case it took ~1-2 seconds per query). As @lightoze suggested you can use `SearchService`, but then you'll get the documents in `ResultSet`, so after you'll need also to call `length` method to get the number of them, which I think is more time consuming rather than sql call. And in my case I do such calls every 5 minutes.
2. There is a [bug](http://fcorti.com/2014/12/08/cmis-queries-alfresco-5-0-c/) in 5.0.c which limits the result of some queries by 1000 docs.

[Here](http://pavelmakhov.com/2015/02/connect-to-alfresco-db/) you can find how to connect to database and [here](http://pavelmakhov.com/2015/05/usefule-alfresco-queries/) some interesting queries including the total number of documents in repo.